# Dropzone spritemap doesnt want to fit on screen

Tags: dropzone.js

Hallo im working with dropzone.js and everthing is working fine i just cant figure out why my spritemap doesnt want to fit on my browser when i reduce the size like on the officiel dropzone page.

Official site http://www.dropzonejs.com
[image: http://www.dropzonejs.com]

My site
[image: my site]

maybe you got some ideas to help me.

Comment: That uses media queries. Do you use media in your css ?

Comment: @Piry the only other thing im using is google street maps and some textfileds

Comment: No, I mean the DropZone example from their website is responsive, so the elements get a different style for different resolutions. Copy the entire css from the demo and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not have a media query set in your css file to handle lower viewport widths, so the content didn't resize.